# Not showing image for new PM

Tags: php, function

I have this code to show the user if they have a new unreaded PM in my system. The problem is, the image don't shows up even if you get a new PM or have readed them all.

The code is like this:

```
<tr class="navHeaderRow">
<td width="15%" align="center">
<img src="images/nav/pms.gif"></td>
<td width="85%" align="left"><div class="navHeader">
<a href="index.php?action=pms" style="text-decoration: none;">Private Messages';
$get_new = mysql_query("SELECT * from messages WHERE recipient = '$this->getuserinfo(username)' and msgread = 'n'");
$amt = mysql_num_rows($get_new);
if ($amt > '0') { 
echo'<img border="0px" src="pm.gif">';
}
echo'</a></div></td></tr>
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: **WARNING:** The `mysql_*` API has been deprecated. Either use `PDO` or `MySQLi`.

Comment: Can I just change from mysql_ to mysqli_?

Comment: @Anthon No, you'll have to make some changes. You'll also want to start using parameterized queries - right now, a username with `'` in it will break your query.

Comment: @ceejayoz Is it hard to convert to mysqli?

Comment: @Anthon Does it matter? The `mysql_*` functions are **gone** in PHP7.

Answer (score 0):

The username sould be variable. So like this 
`$get_new = mysql_query("SELECT * from messages WHERE recipient = '$this->getuserinfo($username)' and msgread = 'n'");`

Comment: Tried that but no change.. I found this a little bit up in the code:

$get_userinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE `username` = '$username'");
$username = mysql_fetch_object($get_userinfo);
return $username->$var;
}

Comment: do you have another idea?